# High side mosfet- Extra pulse on turn off

Tags: mosfet, brushless-dc-motor, motor-controller, mosfet-driver, nmos

I am making a 3 phase motor drive H-bridge using N channel mosfets (IRFB3607) and BJT based custom mosfet driver such that my turn on and turn off time is about 200ns. Right now I am testing the system with a light load of 0.5A at 24V.

[image]

So during turn off, I see something interesting that I can't explain.

Yellow- Output

Blue - Gate

Red - (math) = Blue - Yellow

[image]

The differential signal says that the gate is turning off properly so this is caused by circuit inductance or capacitance of the low side mosfet.

[image]

Obviously there is a lot of stray inductance all over the place. This is supposed to drive an inductive load. But I have a feeling this is something else.

Comment: C19 and C91 look awfully problematic to me. Also, you need to show how the logic gate power rails are derived.

Comment: Logic gates are representations of a complicated driver circuit. C19 & C91 are decoupling capacitors for Bootstrap & control voltage respectively.

Comment: Got fixed by a snubber. I'm not sure why but I feel it is the current through the load inductance charging the low side mosfet capacitance and causing the blip.